# inserting an artificial column in mdx query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, dimension, measure

from some reasons I need to insert an artificial(dummy) column into a mdx expression. (the reason is that i need to obtain a query with specific number of columns )

to ilustrate, this is my sample query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[AFR],[Measures].[IB],[Measures].[IC All],[Measures].[IC_without_material],[Measures].[Nonconformance_PO],[Measures].[Nonconformance_GPT],[Measures].[PM_GPT_Weighted_Targets],[Measures].[PM_PO_Weighted_Targets], [Measures].[AVG_LC_Costs],[Measures].[AVG_MC_Costs]}    ON COLUMNS,
([dim_ProductModel].[PLA].&[SME])
*  ORDER(  {([dim_ProductModel].[Warranty Group].children)} , ([Measures].[Nonconformance_GPT],[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]) ,desc)   
* ([dim_ProductModel].[PLA Text].members  - [dim_ProductModel].[PLA Text].[All]) 
* {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-01-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]} ON ROWS
FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]
```

it is not very important, just some measures and crossjoined dimensions. Now I would need to add f.e. 2 extra columns, I don't care whether this would be a measure with null/0 values or another crossjoined dimension. Can I do this in some easy way without inserting any data into my cube?

In sql I can just write Select  0 or select "dummy1", but here it is not possible neither in ON ROWS nor in ON COLUMNS part of the query.

Thank you very much for your help,

Regards,

Peter

ps: so far I could just insert some measure more times, but I am interested whether there is a possibility to insert really "dummy" column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query just has the measures dimension on columns. The easiest way to extend it by some columns would be to repeat the last measure as many times that you get the correct number of columns.

Another possibility, which may be more efficient in case the last measure is complex to calculate would be to use

```
WITH member Measures.dummy as NULL
SELECT {[Measures].[AFR],[Measures].[IB],[Measures].[IC All],[Measures].[IC_without_material],[Measures].[Nonconformance_PO],[Measures].[Nonconformance_GPT],[Measures].[PM_GPT_Weighted_Targets],[Measures].[PM_PO_Weighted_Targets], [Measures].[AVG_LC_Costs],[Measures].[AVG_MC_Costs],
Measures.dummy, Measures.dummy, Measures.dummy
}
ON COLUMNS,

([dim_ProductModel].[PLA].&[SME])
*  ORDER(  {([dim_ProductModel].[Warranty Group].children)} , ([Measures].[Nonconformance_GPT],[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]) ,desc)   
* ([dim_ProductModel].[PLA Text].members  - [dim_ProductModel].[PLA Text].[All]) 
* {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-01-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]}
ON ROWS

FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]
```

i. e. adding a dummy measure that should not need much computation as many times as you need it to the end of the columns.

Comment: perfect! exactly what I needed. I had previously solution with repeated measure, but this one I find 1. less computationaly complex and 2. it is more obvious that additional columns are there on purpose whereas repeated measures might be more looking as a bug/more confusing for another programmer. thank you one more time.

Comment: @FrankPI please, is there also some way how to repeat or insert dummy variable into rows in this my case? If i try to repeat some dimension i got "the hierarhy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function." ? thank you, even better would be to have "nulls" inbetween my rows. (i need unfortunately some structure in my columns in order to easy use vlookups in excel)

Comment: so far, I solved it with inserting a "calculated column" in data view, where I simply put literal 0 or so  that I can use this column in crossjoin.. it is a little bit dirty, but performance  does not seem to be lower

Comment: just define another dummy member on one or all of the row hierarchies, i. e. `[dim_ProductModel].[PLA]`, `[dim_ProductModel].[Warranty Group]`, `[dim_ProductModel].[PLA Text]` and/or `Dim_Date].[Date Full]` and use those in the rows then.